# Zeros of an entire function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

Given that $f(z)$ is an entire function and is not identically zero. Also $f(z)$ has no zeros on the real axis. Consider a small rectangle $R_{\epsilon(H)}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 3-\epsilon(H)\leq x\leq 3+\epsilon(H),\ 0\leq y\leq H+\epsilon(H)\}$ where $H>4$ and $\epsilon(H)>0$ is a continuous function depending on $H$.

> **Question:** Prove that there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $f(z)$ has no zeros on the boundary of the rectangle $R_{\epsilon(H)}$ whenever $0<\epsilon(H)<\epsilon_0$.

My attempt: We prove the above question by the method of contradiction. If possible let us suppose no such $\epsilon_0$ exists. Then for each $\epsilon(H)>0$, there must exist $\epsilon'(H)$ with $0<\epsilon'(H)<\epsilon(H)$ such that the boundary of the rectangle $R_{\epsilon'(H)}$ has atleast one zero of $f$.

In particular if we take $\epsilon_n(H)=\epsilon^*(H)/2^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0<\epsilon^*(H)\leq 1$, then there exists $\epsilon_{n}'(H)$ such that $0<\epsilon'_n(H)<\epsilon_n(H)=\epsilon^*(H)/2^n$ such that the boundary of $R_{\epsilon_n'(H)}$ has atleast one zero $z_n$ of $f$.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\{\epsilon_n'(H)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing and $\epsilon_n'(H)\to 0^+$ (to see this choose $\epsilon_1'(H)<\epsilon_1(H)$ and then choose $\epsilon_2'(H)<\epsilon_1'(H)$ and $\epsilon_2'(H)<\epsilon^*(H)/2^2$ and we continue this process).

Now we consider a set $A=\{z_n\in \mathbb{C}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $z_n$ are those zeros of $f$ as we have chosen above. Now we can have two cases:

Case $1$: $A$ is an infinite set: Since $\epsilon_n(H)=\epsilon^*(H)/2^n$ so we have $\epsilon^*(H)>\epsilon_1(H)>\epsilon_2(H)>\epsilon_3(H)>...$ and hence all the zeros $z_n$ of set $A$ lie inside the rectangle $R_{\epsilon^*(H)}$ where $0<\epsilon^*(H)\leq 1$ and clearly $R_{\epsilon^*(H)}$ is a bounded set. Hence we get that $A$ is also a bounded set.

So by the Bolzano--Weierstrass theorem, set $A$ has a limit point. Since $f$ is entire so by the Identity theorem since $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ is an infinite bounded subset of the zeros of $f$ and it has a limit point so $f$ must be identically zero which is a contradiction.

Case $2$: $A$ is a finite set:
In this case there are infinitely many $R_{\epsilon_n'(H)}$ having common zeros of $f$, thereby forcing zeros to lie on the real axis (as only the real axis can be common in $R_{\epsilon_n'(H)}$). This again contradicts the fact that $f$ has no zeros on the real axis.

I am thankful to you for helping me in this question.

Comment: You don't need contradiction for question 1. Any compact subset of $C$ must contain a finite number of zeros of an entire non-zero function. Hence, $R_{\epsilon(H)}$ contains a finite number of zeros of $f$.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to prove in question 2. I think it needs to be re-written for clarity.

Comment: @BobbyOcean No, in question 1 I am saying there are no zeros on the boundary of the rectangle.

Comment: All I am saying is that you already know that $R_1$ has a finite number of zeros, say $n$ of them. There are therefore at most, $n$ $\epsilon$'s where $R_\epsilon$ has a zero on the boundary. The rest do not.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Then how does this ensure that there are no zeros on the boundary?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the motivation for either question is, which makes this more difficult to answer. In any case, I do not believe that the first result is true.

I assume that $H \ge 0$ (so that $R_{\epsilon(H)} \neq \emptyset$). Then, consider the entire function:

$$f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, \;\;f(z)=\sinh(2z-3)$$

and $$\epsilon(H) = \lceil H \rceil \frac{\pi}{2} - H$$

where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, note that for any choice of $H$, by construction, the boundary of $R_{\epsilon(H)}$ passes through the point $z = 3+i\lceil H \rceil\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is a zero for $f$, and it may  readily be verified that for any $\epsilon_0>0$, there exists some $H$ such that $\epsilon_0/2 < \epsilon(H) < \epsilon_0$.

---

You might observe that my choice of $\epsilon : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous. Maybe the result is true if it is, but without any motivation for the question, it is not clear that I should have assumed this. Similarly for $H > 4$, the fact that the rectangle is centred about $x = 3$, etc. -- it is completely unclear what relevance any of these constraints have to the question.

Please provide a clearer and better-motivated explanation for both questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about the second question? Is it not correct?

Comment: Your entire function $f(z)$ has a zero at $x=3/2$ on the real axis. But my entire function has no zeros on the real axis.

Comment: @Santevita Good observation, but I hope you see that if I slightly translate my function $f$ vertically and also modify $\epsilon$ suitably, this is still a counterexample. I am sorry, but I am not interested in answering your second question until it is clearer and better-motivated, as I said.

Comment: But for the second question I want a small rectangle  $R_{\epsilon(H)}$  so that the number of zeros on the vertical line L is same as the number of zeros inside this small Rectangle $R_{\epsilon(H)}$. Please help me out.